# Facebook login button not rendering - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-login

In my Rails app users can login with their Facebook account. As of now users just click a link and it logs them in. I want to use [Facebook's login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/login-button) but it is not working.

I follow Facebook's instructions and add the JavaScript SDK to my application.html.erb

Then a place the provided div tags around my link like so

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false">
  <%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) %>
</div>
```

The button doesn't show up. Is there something special I need to do for Rails?

Update:
Using Pavan's method I get:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/users/auth/facebook":String
```

This is my code:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
    <%= image_tag image_path('facebook-login.jpg') %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What does you mean by the button doesn't show up?

Comment: @Pavan The button never appears. I still see just the link. It is as if I never even added the div tags.

Comment: Is my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
   Sign in with <%= provider.to_s.titleize %>
   <%= image_tag image_path('facebook-login.jpg') %>
<% end %>
```

If you are passing a block, you should not be passing the '**Label**'

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Javascript SDK won't render the login button if the `div` has a link in it. Remove the link that the button will be rendered:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>
```

The client-side authentication workflow will be slightly different than linking directly to omniauth. Check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication) for details. Ryan starts talking about client-side authentication about 7 minutes in. Clicking the login button button will automatically call `FB.login` when clicked.

If you don't need client-side authentication and you're just looking to render a button, it may be easiest to download an image icon like Pavan suggests.

Comment: When I try adding an image I get undifined method error for `stringify_keys`. My looks like this:

`<%= link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider) do %>
        <%= image_tag image_path('facebook-login.jpg') %>
        <% end %>`